# Win32 - WndProc as class member, pointer to class instance is always nullptr

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to wrap WndProc as a private class member. I read the trick is to use two WndProc functions, one of them static. I set `cbWndExtra` to the size of a `LONG_PTR` and tried setting and getting the pointer to my class instance using `SetWindowLongPtr` and `GetWindowLongPtr`. I am then checking if it's a nullptr and calling the second WndProc if it's not. But for some reason `pApplication` always is a `nullptr` so my application is always running the `DefWindowProc` without running my own WndProc.

**Application.h**

```
private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) noexcept;
    LRESULT HandleMsg(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) noexcept;
```

**Application.cpp**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Application::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) noexcept
{
    Application* pApplication;

    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        pApplication = static_cast<Application*>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pApplication));
    }
    else
    {
        pApplication = reinterpret_cast<Application*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA));
    }

    if (pApplication)
        return pApplication->HandleMsg(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I do not see where you are creating an actual `Application` object.  C++ requires creation of an actual object -- messing around with pointers to create fake objects like this: `reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams`  doesn't do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was trying to get a pointer to an already instantiated object that is calling the static WndProc function so I could call one of its member functions within the static one. Your comment let me rethink some stuff I was doing at a higher level, so I managed to find the issue of not even properly setting the pointer I tried to receive in the WndProc function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
I accidentally passed a `nullptr` instead of `this` to `CreateWindowA` which obviously didn't even set the `lParam` so I wasn't able to retrieve it afterwards.